# How to add 5 day to selected current date

Tags: mysql

How can I select a current date and add 5 day?

I have the current date with some like:

```
select date_format(now(),'%d-%m-%Y') as date_now;
```

And I need the date with 5 day add, and I have ( with error):

```
select date_format(now(),'%d-%m-%Y', interval 5 day) as date_5_day;
```

How can I add 5 day to the current date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try CURDATE() - function that retrieves the current date without time information.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY);
```

CURDATE() reference: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp

Comment: SELECT date_format(date_add(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY), '%d-%m-%Y');

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(`your_field_name`, INTERVAL 5 DAY);
```

See more here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

if you don't have the current date already in the table then insert it:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2, col3, .. , colN)
VALUES('val1', 'val2', 'val2', ... , 'valN', NOW())
```

then apply the previous command

Comment: i try  "select DATE_ADD(date_format(now(),'%d-%m-%Y'), INTERVAL 5 DAY);"  but result is NULL .

Comment: Put the name of the column you want to change. The column needs to have dates on it !!!

Comment: sorry , i haven't a tablet with values, i need just ger the current date of system and add 5 day.

Comment: I just need add 5 days to the current date in Y-m-d format , thank !

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
DATE_ADD(DateField, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Comment: i try  "select DATE_ADD(date_format(now(),'%d-%m-%Y'), INTERVAL 5 DAY);"  but result is NULL .

Answer (score 0):

curdate() work to give me current date,and add 5 day :

```
select date_format(date_add(curdate(), interval 5 day),'%d-%m-%Y');
```

and this the current day :

```
select date_format(now(),'%d-%m-%Y');
```

thanks!!